# How to fill a tableview with sudzc? (My property dont work)

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview, sudzc

I have a class that uses sudzc. All works fine, with NSLog I can watch the data of my web services, but when I want to use an array and then use that array in other place, the property is null. I want to fill a table view with the data of the web services, but I can't, How could do it?

This is my class

```
       //
//  RootViewController.m
//  StratargetMovil
//
//  Created by Giovanni Cortés on 30/03/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Page2.h"

@interface RootViewController ()
@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize myData = _myData;
@synthesize empresaID = _empresaID;
@synthesize datos = _datos;
@synthesize idUnidadNegocio = _idUnidadNegocio;
@synthesize idArray = _idArray;

-(NSString *)empresaID
{
    _empresaID = @"fce";
    return _empresaID;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    // I want to fill the table view but dont work
    EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc *service = [[EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc alloc] init];
    [service ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresa:self EmpresaId:self.empresaID];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.datos = nil;
    self.myData = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}



// Lo de la tabla
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.myData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.myData objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Muestra la vista 2 cuando se selecciona una fila
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    self.idUnidadNegocio = [self.idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    Page2 *nextNavigator = [[Page2 alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextNavigator animated:YES];
    [nextNavigator release];


}

// -------------------------------------------------
// Consultar unidades organizaciones por empresa
- (void) ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresaHandler: (id) value {

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }               


    // Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
    NSMutableArray *unidadOrganizacional = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.myData = [[[NSMutableArray array] init] autorelease];

    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        EWSUnidadNegocio *empresa = [[EWSUnidadNegocio alloc] init];
        empresa = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        [unidadOrganizacional addObject:[empresa Descripcion]];

    }

    self.myData = unidadOrganizacional;

}
 -(void)onload:(id)value
{
    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }               


    // Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
    NSMutableArray *unidadOrganizacional = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.myData = [[[NSMutableArray array] init] autorelease];

    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        EWSUnidadNegocio *empresa = [[EWSUnidadNegocio alloc] init];
        empresa = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%ld -- %@", [empresa Id], [empresa Descripcion]); // With this I can watch the data in the console
        [unidadOrganizacional addObject:[empresa Descripcion]];

    }

    self.myData = unidadOrganizacional; // self.myData in another place is null
}


}
@end
```

My data is

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myData;

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is doing nothing for you:

```
self.myData = [[[NSMutableArray array] init] autorelease];

...

self.myData = unidadOrganizacional;
```

You are assigning myData then immediately reassigning it.

Skip the first initialization and just do this:

```
self.myData = [unidadOrganizacional mutableCopy];
```

I suspect you are losing the pointer to the unidadOrganizacional array at some point and that is why you are getting null for myData.

Personally though I would just do this initialize myData in the viewDidLoad call and then add the objects to myData directly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    

    self.myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // I want to fill the table view but dont work
    EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc *service = [[EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc alloc] init];
    [service ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresa:self EmpresaId:self.empresaID];
}
```

and then:

```
- (void) ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresaHandler: (id) value {

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }               


    // Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;

    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        EWSUnidadNegocio *empresa = [[EWSUnidadNegocio alloc] init];
        empresa = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.myData addObject:[empresa Descripcion]];
    }
}

-(void)onload:(id)value
{
    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }               


    // Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;

    for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
    {
        EWSUnidadNegocio *empresa = [[EWSUnidadNegocio alloc] init];
        empresa = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%ld -- %@", [empresa Id], [empresa Descripcion]); // With this I can watch the data in the console
        [self.myData addObject:[empresa Descripcion]];

    }
}
```

You may want to clear out myData before the `ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresa` call, I'm not really sure what the different between that and `onload` is really.  It looks like they are duplicates of each other.

Good luck!

Comment: It do not work =(. But I noticed something, first the table view is show in the popover (I show the table view in a popover) and then, in the terminal is show the data. I think that do not show the data because the data is loaded later

Comment: Yes, you will need to reload the tableView when you get the new data.  `[tableView reloadData];` after myData is filled.  I would fill the popover with a little loading animation until myData is done populating then run a reloadData and kill the loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think `myData` autoreleased.
You can alloc and init the `myData` array but not auto-/release it. (remove autorelease at the `myData` allocation in the 
`ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresaHandler` method)

Don't forget to add a dealloc method for releasing the `myData` (and other) properties.